# How to freeze a huggingface model?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I use

```
        for p in model.parameters():
            p.requires_grad = False
```

to freeze a T5 model (t5-small), but when I print parameters that require grad, there is still one parameter with the size `32121x512`. What is this? Is it the embeddings  matrix? Should I freeze it too? It seems backward gradients affect this one remaining parameter

Answer (score 0):

It seems I called `model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))` after freezing parameters, and it can reset the embeddings require_grad to True